# Use NGINX as a reverse proxy for Object storage to serve WEBP conditionally

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, minio, object-storage

I'm using a location config like this in Nginx for serving WEBP when the user supports it

```
    map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
        default   "";
        "~*webp"  ".webp";
    }

    server {
    #...
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$ {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
        }
    #...
    }
```

my problem is that I want to use the same strategy but when I'm using an object-storage (Minio - S3 compatible)

so I'm wondering what is the best way to replace this part:

```
try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
```

with something like

```
try_proxy_pass http://minio$uri$webp_suffix http://minio$uri =404;
```

Comment: Why would you `proxy_pass` to an object storage provider? That will negate most of the benefits of using object storage provider, because all the requests for images have to still go through your server? Also, `image_filter` is a filter running on your nginx server. It cannot do anything to the images in object storage.

Comment: First Because Im hosting my own HA minio object storage cluster secondly currently im testing that and image_filter also works with proxy_pass to minio

Comment: also, I edited my question to be less confusing

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for this that I put together myself.

if you want to read more here is a link to a repo that I made for testing and Proof of concept that this solution is working:https://github.com/erfantkerfan/cdn-nginx-image-optimization

```
    recursive_error_pages on;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
    proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files /dev/null @image_webp;
    }

    location @image_webp {
        proxy_pass http://minio_servers$uri$webp_suffix;

        image_filter_jpeg_quality 95;
        image_filter_webp_quality 100;
        image_filter_interlace on;
        image_filter_buffer 100M;
        image_filter resize $width $height;
        image_filter crop $width $height;
        image_filter_transparency on;

        error_page 404 415 = @image;
    }

    location @image {
        proxy_pass http://minio_servers$uri;

        image_filter_jpeg_quality 95;
        image_filter_webp_quality 100;
        image_filter_interlace on;
        image_filter_buffer 100M;
        image_filter resize $width $height;
        image_filter crop $width $height;
        image_filter_transparency on;
    }
}
```